# i cant find, or download iisforward.dll. where is it?

Tags: iis, weblogic, was

I need iisforward.dll. but I can`t find iisforward.dll.

How can I get that file?

++
It is not with iisproxy.dll.
Also, I try to use `Everything` program.

Comment: What is the version of your WebLogic IIS plug-in ?
The iisforward.dll file was removed from the IIS plug-in at the 11.1.1.4 release, and is not needed in the current versions of the plug-in.

Comment: You can download it in this url. @EmmanuelCollin 's comment is right. https://www.pconlife.com/download/otherfile/164411/e2fcb2ba00b56582c8a3454d7751e32a/

Comment: thanks. I use weblogic 14. so I dont need iisforward. thanks to help.

Comment: @swz You maybe want IIS reverse agent Tomcat website. You can add ARR and Microsoft URL Rewrite 2.0, and restart iis after installed.